# Block Subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, block, subdirectory

i need to block sub directory in this way

http://subdomain.nomesite.ext

and i want to use htaccess

someone can help me?

i cannot access to the sub , i must block from the root of site

Answer (score 0):

You can just put this line in the root .htaccess of `subdirecory.nomesite.ext`:

```
Deny from All
```

Comment: i cannot access to the sub , i must block from the root of site.

Comment: What do you by `i cannot access to the sub`? Is it sub-directory or subdomain?

Comment: it is   nametoblock.namesite.ext ok subdomain, but i cannot access to the subdomain , how can i resolve?

Comment: I am unable to understand your comments. Can you clarify with examples?

Comment: I have payed my host to do some page  SEO in my site , so they have added  this sub domain , but google says that are doorway so i obtain only penalty for all site, i want to block google crawler to access this subdomain, i have spoke with my host but they said that i must wait 1 years because i have paid for 1 years, some idea?

Comment: Ok but how come you cannot access this subdomain? How is thus subdomain setup in Apache config? What is root directory of subdomain?

Comment: i don't know how is set, it is an hosting solution, no VPS, no Dedicated,

Comment: I asked so many questions and if you this is what you have to say then I'm afraid then your problem cannot be resolved.

Comment: No problem  anubhava and  thanks for your time. Now I'll try to ask again to my host to erase this page.